# Finding the count of a keyword in HTML using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to find out the keyword to total number of words ratio in a webpage, I am using jsoup to parse the HTML of the webpages. I want to know how to find out the count of a keyword in a webpage using JSOUP. I want to know if there is a function in JSOUP to do that Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a methods for counting words in Jsoup, since JSoup is about parsing html/xml only. If you  are okay with getting all text (including stuff that might not be rendered due to css rules like hiding) you can simply use Element.text(). See [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) for details.

```
Element body = doc.body();
String allText = body.text();
```

Now you can do all sorts of word processing with the string in `allText`. Good libraries for word processing might be [apache lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) or simpler stuff like [Wordcounter](https://github.com/stoyanr/Wordcounter)